# Python intersection with substrings

Tags: python, string, set, substring, intersection

I have two sets:

```
a = set(['this', 'is', 'an', 'apple!'])
b = set(['apple', 'orange'])
```

I want to find if there are any (b) in (a) including substrings. 
normally I would do:

```
c = a.intersection(b)
```

However, in this example it would return an empty set as 'apple' != 'apple!'

Assuming I cannot remove characters from (a) and hopefully without creating loops, is there a way for me to find a match?

Edit: I would like for it to return a match from (b) e.g. I would like to know if 'apple' is in set (a), I do not want it to return 'apple!'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing the equality check via `==`, you can use `in` for substring match which also covers equality:

```
>>> [x for ele in a for x in b if x in ele]
["apple"]
```

Comment: This is working but it seems to be returning ["apple!"]. How can I make it return ["apple"]?

Comment: You should change the first `ele` to `x` which basically collects the items from `b` instead of `a`. Updated the code.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help. I am new to python and hadn't seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

Using sets is actually of little benefit if you are not searching for exact matches, if the words always start with the same substring, sorting and bisecting will be a more efficient approach i.e `O(n log n)` vs `O(n^2)`:

```
a = set(['this', 'is', 'an', 'apple!'])
b = set(['apple', 'orange'])

srt = sorted(a)
from bisect import bisect

inter = [word for word in b if srt[bisect(srt, word, hi=len(a))].startswith(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is:

```
any(x in y for x in b for y in a)
```

It's a loop, but you can't escape that. Any solution will at least have an implied loop somewhere.

Comment: This works but only returns true or false. Is there a way to make is specify what the match is?

Comment: @ozgur's answer will work. Your question wording implied that you only wanted a boolean.